# UiPickerView moves to origin when running in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, position

When I run the simulator, the UiPickerView sets its position to the origin although it is in the proper position in the storyboard:

[Here is the image when it is positioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LBO3.png)

[Here is how it looks when running on a simulator:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWeDU.png)

[Here is the code I am running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkwPM.png)

Comment: Have you added layout guides to tell the app where to position the picker view? Reader about auto layout if you are not familiar with how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read more about autolayout. Its strange because the two buttons are positioned just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lines is not wrong at all.
You need to check again your auto layout constraints of UIPickerView in Storyboard file.
Maybe it miss some constrains to layout correctly!
You need to upload current constrains of UIPickerView to receive more helpful guide from other developers.